# XML is parsed as HTML when called through iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, iframe

I'm trying to show an xml file in a HTML page using iframe by bringing the content through jQuery by altering the source attribute.

When I open the iframe on my browser (Firefox/Chrome/IE8), it opens fine just as below:

[image: Opening the XML in a separate tab/window]

But when the same document rendered using an iframe, the xml is being parsed as HTML and displayed as shown in the image below:

[image: XML on being called in iframe]

I have set proper headers and when I checked on the network tabs in the console, it is showing proper result:

[image: XML result proper in networks tab under Console]

I'm not able to figure out a proper way which will display the XML properly under the iframe. Tried various solutions posted on different forums but it does not seem to be working.

Thank you!

Comment: What you are seeing in the first screenshot is a browser-specific feature for rendering XML when the top-level frame doesn't have a stylesheet. You shouldn't rely on that functionality. I would imagine that there are libraries out there that render XML markup as HTML, or you could write your own pretty easily.

Comment: @JLRishe: Can you point me to any libraries that might be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of any specifically.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. In the end did it work for you in anyway? Because for me doesn't work to have a nice view. I used textarea (the closest to a xml view), but looks like is opened in notepad. I try to have the browser view (your first picture), did you manage to display a nice view? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If raw content display is ok for you, then you have the following options.

Wrap things in the `xmp` or `pre` tag (there is also `textarea`) - maybe combined with jQuery escaping:

```
<pre>
  ${fn:escapeXml('
    <!-- the raw content - code, xml --> 
  ')};
</pre>
```

Comment: Hi I have the same problem and I put the xml in a textarea. Now I can see the xml and the structure, but it looks like a notepad xml. Is there any chance to make it look like in the first picture (native browser view)?

Comment: jus to show an XML in raw structure u dont need iframe.just pre tag is enough.But to load it as an XML File load

Answer (score 0):

If you install the [XML Tree extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xml-tree/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb), Chrome will show nicely formatted XML in an iframe. As a bonus, you get some XPath functionality.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it like this...

I am loading the `xml` files into an iframe from an anchor tag with a `target` attribute. e.g.:

```
<a href="${file.path}" target="displayFrame">...
```

What seemed to force the iframe to render the `xml` as plain text was to append an arbitrary (or even empty) query string parameter to the file URL, as follows:

```
<a href="${file.path}?" target="displayFrame">...
```

Note the '?'.

- I am serving the `xml` file as Content-Type: `'text/plain'`.
- I have the attribute `type="text/plain"` on the iframe

Disclaimer: I am not sure exactly how or why this works; i.e., how it tricks Chrome into rendering the file differently, nor have I tested this extensively across other browsers.